# Не работают кнопки в OnTouch()

Tags: android

Кнопки не работают при нажатии на них .... Вроде бы этот код switch работал на onClick() ... не подскажите почему это происходит ??

Вот код на onTouch()

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
String dates;
String dd;
String de;
Button btn, btn2, btn3;
TextView txw, txw2;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    this.btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    this.btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    this.txw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txw);
    this.txw2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txw2);

    this.btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


            dates = "A";
            txw.setText(btn.getText().toString());
            dd = btn.getText().toString();

            switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btn:
                        dd = btn.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn2:
                        dd = btn2.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn3:
                        dd = btn3.getText().toString();
                        break;
                }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

   //                    int[] location = new int[2];
   //                    btn2.getLocationOnScreen(location);
 //                    int x = location[0];
 //                    int y = location[1];

  //                    Log.e(TAG, "onTouch: getX = " + x);
  //                    Log.e(TAG, "onTouch: getY = " + y);

            if (X >= btn.getX() && X <= btn.getX() + btn.getHeight() && Y     >= btn.getY() && Y <= btn.getY() + btn.getWidth()) {
                dates = btn.getText().toString();
            }
            if (X >= btn2.getX() && X <= btn2.getX() + btn2.getWidth() &&      Y >= btn2.getY() && Y <= btn2.getY() + btn2.getHeight()) {
                dates = dd + btn2.getText().toString();
                de = dates;
            }

            if (X >= btn3.getX() && X <= btn3.getX() + btn3.getHeight()       && Y >= btn3.getY() && Y <= btn3.getY() + btn3.getWidth()) {
                dates = de + btn3.getText().toString();
            }

            txw.setText(dates);

            if (dates.equals("ABC")){
                txw2.setText("ABC");
            } else {
                txw2.setText("WOrd");
            }

            break;
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Судя по вашему коду onTouch должен срабатывать только при нажатии на кнопку btn, а не на "кнопки". Это так?

Answer (score 0):

судя по коду, вы ожидаете, что листенер будет работать для всех. Для этого его нужно "подвесить всем", а не только 1 кнопке:

```
this.btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
this.btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
this.btn3.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

вместо

```
this.btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
```